# Is a custom IDispatch with native meta-programming possible?

Tags: c, windows, com

Recently I've been looking at how the `IDispatch` works. Below is an example of how an automation client may call a method of an automation server object, which implements `IDispatch`:

```
HRESULT hresult;
IDispatch * pdisp = (IDispatch *)NULL;
DISPID dispid;
OLECHAR * szMember = "color";

// Code that sets a pointer to the dispatch (pdisp) is omitted.

hresult = pdisp->GetIDsOfNames(
   IID_NULL,
   &szMember,
   1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
   &dispid);

pdisp->Invoke(
   dispid,
   ...
)
```

When implementing a server, this suggests to me that you could implement `GetIDOfNames` as:

```
HRESULT GetIDsOfNames(
  REFIID   riid,
  LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
  UINT     cNames,
  LCID     lcid,
  DISPID   *rgDispId
){
  rgDispId = 10;
  return S_OK;
};
```

In this way we tell the client, essentially, that all method calls are okay, and all method calls will call method with `DISPID==10`.

```
myObject->a();
myObject->ab();
myObject->abc();
myObject->abcd();
//^^ Are all valid and will all call DispID 10.
```

So my question is, Can we somehow store the name that was called, such that our DispID 10 method, will know which method is being called?

---

Note: The ultimate goal of this is to build a COM server which has the ability to be a COM server for other COM clients, which might lack the capability/knowledge of being COM servers themselves.

Comment: IDispatch (Automation) was designed for hi level language (ie: VB at that time) and scripting languages (VBScript, etc.). Anyway, you can come up with a dispid that correspond to a name if you want. It can be any value (except some hardcoded ones found in oaidl.h, like DISPID_NEWENUM) But note some languages (I don't remember exactly) can cache the dispid. And I don't really understand what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: @SimonMourier The core routes of what I wanted to do was build a ComServerFactory class for VBA within VBA. The best way to build such a class in my mind was to delegate calls to the COM object to a handler function, which could use the name of the functions and params to execute the code and return results dynamically. An alternative would be to dynamically assign callback functions and DispIDs at runtime. I'm not sure which is more viable.

Comment: You might be looking for [`IDispatchEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/winscript/reference/idispatchex-interface). It's there to support scripting languages like JavaScript, where you can manufacture a new property on an object simply by assigning to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that does sound quite a lot like what I want! Thanks!